# Populating subfield from other collections (not refs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to populate subfields of a document, which are not defined as refs. The problem is that mongoose keeps returning null, whenever I try to fetch the document and populate the fields.

I will try to make this a generic question. I haven't found an answer anywhere online.

`schemaA`:

```
const schemaA = new Schema({
  before: {
    type: Object,
    default: {}
  },
  after: {
    type: Object,
    default: {}
  }
});

module.exports = SchemaA = mongoose.model("schemaA", schemaA);
```

`schemaB`:

```
const schemaB = new Schema({
  someField: {
    subFieldA: {
      type: String
    },
    subFieldB: {
      type: String
    }
  }
});

module.exports = SchemaB = mongoose.model("schemaB", schemaB);
```

And an example document that would exist in `schemaA` is:

```
_id: ObjectId('5e4ab79d9d3ce8633aedf524')
before: {
  someField: {
    subFieldA: ObjectId('5e4ab74f9d3ce8633aedf2eb'),
    subFieldB: ObjectId('5e4ab74f9d3ce8633aedf2ep')
  },
}
after: {
  someField: {
    subFieldA: ObjectId('5e4ab74f9d4ce8633aedf2eb'),
    subFieldB: ObjectId('5e4ab74f9d3ce8639aedf2ep')
  },
}
date: 2020-02-17T15:56:13.340+00:00
```

My query:

```
const schemaAs = await SchemaA.find()
  .populate(
    "before.someField.subFieldA, before.someField.subFieldB, after.someField.subFieldA, after.someField.subFieldB"
  )
```

But this query returns `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason you are not adding a reference?

Comment: Yup, it's an action logger. The action could me a change or edit made to any collection. So the `before` and `after` can't be tied to any one collection.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Dynamic References](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref).
This lets you set what collection you are referencing as a property to each individual document, instead of hard coding it to one specific collection.

As far as I know, it is not possible to populate a property without any reference.